# How to read fixed size of bytes turn by turn in continuation using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, size, byte, fixed, continuations

I have one binary file and I want to read this file like first four bytes then next 5 bytes then next 3 bytes till file ends.

I am able to read file using each_byte but I want to categorize all these bytes in groups in sequence they are stored in file.

I am able to read this using following lines but dont know how to read in fixed sized blocks with continutation.

```
File.open('myfile','rb') do |file|
file.each_byte {|ch| print "#{ch.chr}:#{ch}\t"}
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand but maybe something like:

```
file.read.scan(/(.{4})(.{5})(.{3})/).each do |a,b,c|
    puts "first 4 bytes: #{a}"
    puts "bytes 5 to 10: #{b}"
    puts "3 more bytes: #{c}"
end
```

Comment: its near to what I want to do but I want like script prints line "first 4 bytes" then prints contents of first 4 bytes then prints "bytes 5 to 10 " and below it contents of bytes from 5 to 10 and so on till file ends.

Comment: ok but what to do if after some fixed sized blocks I want to print rest of variable length blocks how can I print them in one go? I mean what I need to use in regexp instead of /(.{4})/ ?

Comment: Also want to print this in hex or some other encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really fast, but it's ruby :-)

```
file.each_byte.slice_before({pattern: [4,5,3].cycle, left: 0}) do |ele, state|
  if state[:left] == 0
    state[:left] = state[:pattern].next
    true
  else
    state[:left] -= 1
    false
  end
end
```